# Stop UIView leaving container with UIPanGesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have managed to stop my UIView going outside of the container with the pan gesture but what I am struggling to achieve is to stop it at its edges. Currently it goes right to the last pixel edge and not the edge of the moveable view.

I tried changing the frame value which I think is the way to go but couldn't produce the right results. Not sure how close I have got or if there is an easier way?

How would I stop it at its edges of the moveable view instead of the last pixel?
[image]

```
//Container is self.sliderContainer
//Green Block is sender.view which has a UIGesture applied

    var location = sender.locationInView(self.view)

    var newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sliderContainer.frame.width, self.sliderContainer.frame.height)

    let obstacleViewFrame = self.view.convertRect(self.sliderContainer.frame, fromView: self.sliderContainer.superview)

        // Check if the touch is inside the obstacle view
        if CGRectContainsPoint(obstacleViewFrame, location) {

            sender.view!.center.x = sender.view!.center.x + translation.x

            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add a better image? What exactly is moving and where do you want it to stop? What is your view hierarchy?

Comment: A gif and more code would help

Comment: @Sulthan I have updated the pic for you

Comment: You don't have to do `convertToRect`. You can ask directly for `var location = sender.locationInView(self.sliderContainer)` and then check using `CGRectContainsPoint(self.sliderContainer.bounds, location)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing it the simplest way, not limiting the gesture, only making sure the rect won't go out of bounds:

```
let movingView = sender.view!
let minCenterX = movingView.frame.size.width / 2
let maxCenterX = self.sliderContainer.frame.width - movingView.frame.size.width / 2

let newCenterX = movingView.center.x + translation.x
movingView.center.x = min(maxCenterX, max(minCenterX, newCenterX))
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan. Your solution works as well. I tweaked it a bit by adding `sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)` so it didn't move too fast.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are basing the movement of the sender view in the slide based on the coordinates of the touch and not the frame of `sender.view`.

```
let senderViewFrame = self.view.convertRect(sender.view!.frame, fromView: sender.view!.superview)
let insetSenderViewFrame = CGRectInset(senderViewFrame, 0.0, 10.0 /*or whatever's needed*/)
let obstacleViewFrame = self.view.convertRect(self.sliderContainer.frame, fromView: self.sliderContainer.superview)

// Check if the sender view is inside the obstacle view
if CGRectContainsRect(obstacleViewFrame, insetSenderViewFrame) {
    sender.view!.center.x = sender.view!.center.x + translation.x
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeffery. This produces an error `Cannot invoke 'CGRectContainsPoint' with an argument list of type '(CGRect, CGRect)` as the second variable need to be a CGPoint

Comment: @Allreadyhome Sorry, I did that off the top of my head. Replace `CGRectContainsPoint` with `CGRectContainsRect`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't let me drag the Green UIView after using this code.

Comment: @Allreadyhome I see now that self.view is taller than the slider. You can use `CGRectInset()` to height. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks is working. Is only just getting stuck at the edge now. I need to figure out how to re-enable it to allow it to move back.